# can we make payment to multiple parties at a same time in authorize.net method?

Tags: php, api, magento, magento-1.5, authorize.net

Like for example if a payment is made by a customer , it should be paid to site owner, to the one who posted the product(say for example vendor) and also to affiliate.

Mean everyone will get its share.

I have done nothing so far on it and don know whether or not it is even possible. i will like to integrate it in magento if it is possible.

Comment: Have you consulted an accountant about this? Its a fair question but practically I don't see this working for the accounts side of the business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with Authorize.Net. You need to use [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) for this.